# Problems with align numbering?

Tags: align, typography

Consider the following:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs,amsmath}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{align}
    V &= S-S_2^* \ln S+ B\left( I_1-{I_1}_2^* \ln I_1\right) +C\left(I_2-{I_2}_2^* \ln I_2\right) + D\left( J -J_2^* \ln J\right)\\
    &+E\left(A-A_2^* \ln A\right).
    \end{align}
    \end{document}
```

Why is numbered on both lines? how can i number it only once?

Comment: The `align` numbers all lines. If you don't want one, use `\nonumber` on it. For example, at end of second line: `E (A-A_2^* \ln A). \nonumber`.

Comment: possibly better as this is simply a wrapped long expression, do not use `align` use `multline` and remove the `&`

Comment: Unrelated: you use of `\left...\right` here does not do much other than making your code harder to read. It is generally better to only add `\left...\right` when they are really needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of choices, namely `split` and `multline`.

I'd not try to squeeze the fourth summand in the first line, in either case.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
V &= S-S_2^* \ln S+ B(I_1-{I_1}_2^* \ln I_1) +C(I_2-{I_2}_2^* \ln I_2) \\
  &\quad+ D(J -J_2^* \ln J) + E(A-A_2^* \ln A).
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{multline}
V = S-S_2^* \ln S+ B(I_1-{I_1}_2^* \ln I_1) + C(I_2-{I_2}_2^* \ln I_2) \\
  + D(J -J_2^* \ln J) + E(A-A_2^* \ln A).
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you've been taught to always use `\left(` and `\right)`, forget it. It's not leading to better typesetting, but rather to disputable output.